# Can we connect, and use sqlalchemy and mysql.connector together in our Python code?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb, mysql-connector

So I have my Python code, and it's working on `mysql.connecto`r and `,`y,  I was wondering can I use both `sql alchemy` and raw `sql` queries together,  having the best of both worlds?

I tried doing that but you know I got a weird error.

Comment: Yes. Showing what you have done and the "weird error" would be necessary to resolve this. Edit the question with details.

Comment: What exactly did you do and which error did you get?

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without the exact error, but it is possible to use both SQLAlchemy and SQL Raw queries simultaneously. Here's a small example in Python:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text, Table, Column, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Creating a basic user table using SQL Alchemy
user_table = Table('user', metadata,
                   Column('username', String, primary_key=True))
metadata.create_all(engine)

# Assuming you have data in your database you can query it using SQL Alchemy
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
query_result = session.query(user_table).filter_by(username="NervousSolider").first()
sqlalchemy_username = query_result.username

# You can do the same thing using Raw SQL
result = engine.execute(text("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = 'NervousSolider'")).first()
raw_sql_username = result.username

# Both should give you the same value
assert sqlalchemy_username == raw_sql_username
```